Do features with high variance contribute more to top principal components that explain much of the variance in dataset and vice versa?
The first principal components capture the most variance in the dataset. Does that mean, when we look at the weights (or the loading scores), the top principal components will have high absolute weights for the features with higher variance ? and, vice-versa, the bottom principal components will have high absolute weights for the features with lower variance ?

Not necessarily.
I can't give you the math, but a) I've seen cases where this doesn't happen. b) Intuitively, if you had one variable (or feature) with high variance that was unrelated to any other feature, it would not be in the first component, it would be one of the last. Also, PCA is sometimes based on the correlations and sometimes the covariances. If one feature has a much higher variance than the others, then using the correlation matrix is appropriate. Otherwise, you could just multiply a feature by 100 and change everything -- that's silly. "Length" is not more or less important if you change from kilometers to meters.
